# Android Is there a way to know which applications are displaying a notification in notification area?

Tags: android, notifications

I'd like to know if there is a way to know which applications are displaying a notification in notification area or which are the notifications that are displayed.

Many thanks at all

Answer (score 2):

I believe that all applications you install that request permissions to access the notification pane are capable of creating notifications, and I guess most apps have that permission.

If the reason you like to know this is because you have some app spamming you with notifications, at least in in Jellybean you can press and hold on the nottification and a drop-down option appears saying "app info" if you click on it it will take you to the app info pane for that app and allow you to uninstall it.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer but I'd like to know it from code and programmatically...